# Is there any way to find string lenght without using any inbuilt fuctions in java?

Tags: java, string, string-length

I know there are various inbuilt functions, using which we can count string length like `lastIndexOf()`, by converting a string into a char array and counting iteration. There is a way in C programming `for(i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; ++i);` .
how to count string length in java like in C mentioned above.

Update:
Yes, there are these methods `String.length()`, `String.toCharArray()`. But if there are any other hard code way to find the string length.

Comment: Pretty much just what you said. ```String.toCharArray()``` then count each iteration until you get an ```ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException```. But...why?

Comment: Yes, sir, it is easier and readable with these functions but if there is any other way, I just wanted to know. Thanks

Comment: You could make it like C. Just append `'\0'` to the end of your string, and use the method from C.

Comment: "*there are various inbuilt functions, using which we can count string length like lastIndexOf()*" `lastIndexOf` doesn't provide length of array, but last index which holds specified value. "*if there are any other hard code way to find the string length*" what do you mean by *hard code* here? Can you include example of *what* you are searching and rationale explaining *why* / *how you want to use it*?

Comment: @all Whatever you do with a `String`, you'll be calling built-in methods of `String` or of `StringBuilder` (in case of appending).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java is an object-oriented language, where instances are encapsulated, and you access instance properties by calling methods (or directly accessing fields, if they are exposed / not private).

In Java, `String` is a built-in class with instances and methods, other than in C, where a string is something like an array of characters without any encapsulation.

So, whatever you do with a `String`, you'll end up calling built-in methods of that class, e.g.:

- `toCharArray()` is a built-in method.
- `charAt()` is a built-in method.

So, use the straightforward `String.length()` method.